# MongoDB use match and NOT aggregation

Tags: mongodb

how can I use $match and $not in aggregation in MongoDB?
here is code and I want use $not instead of $in

```
 db.test.aggregate([
               { 
                 $match: {
                      $and: [ 
                          {type: {$in: ["TOYS"]}}

                      ]
                 }
               }
              ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) the operator:

```
$nin selects the documents where:

the field value is not in the specified array or
the field does not exist.
```

**Example:**

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
             type: { $nin: [ 'TOYS' ] } 
            }
        },

    ]
);
```